# When do you drop a tier and where do you land?

Tags: league-of-legends

With season 4 they enabled Tier dropping against boosted or ebay accounts. While I really find this a good thing I ask myself when you will drop a Tier. I heard that you need the MMR of division 5 below your current Tier (Plat 5 League + Gold 5 MMR + Lose = Drop) and I also have some friends that lost around 15 games in a row (because they have a boosted account) but they didn't drop out of the Tier.

Also when you drop, where will you land? Will you be in Division 1 of your current Tier or will you instantly drop to the Tier where your MMR is?

Comment: Well I'm not asking whether or not you can drop, but I'm asking **when** it is happening and **where** you will land.

Comment: The title of the linked question asks 'can you drop?' the question body asks '... and if so, what criteria must you meet?' The currently accepted answer addresses both can you drop and when. It and also has some mention of where you land. If you are unsatisfied with the current answer there, I think it is a good candidate for a bounty.

Comment: I believe i read that its where your mmr places you, but I can't find the red post

Answer (score 0):

You will drop one division at a time, and as you progressively lose games you will drop even further.